# Cannot get fur on hands

Tags: particles, hair

I have a character I am applying fur to and all seems to be working well except for his hands and feet.  I am applying fur to his hands and feet using the weight paint mode with the hands in total red.  The hair/ fur emitter setting is at 2000 and children have been added with interpolation. I am using Blender 2.75 with Cycles render.  I can get fur on the wrists but the hand and fingers do not appear or are so short nothing appears.  Here is a picture of my problem.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: hair fur results on arm and hand]

Comment: You may want to try the latest build from [our buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download), some issues here were fixed recently (both recent regressions and old problems).

Comment: Thanks for the help...found the problem. I had some polygons that were turned inside out and the hair was growing inside.